# Using a MySQL query to count records with time ranges at regular intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count, recursive-query

Given a MySQL table that tracks how long a visitor spent at a location, what would be a suitable query to count the total visitors at 5 minute intervals over the course of a day?

```
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| end_timestamp   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| start_timestamp | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| visitor_id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| location_id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

E.g. results might look like this:

```
+---------------------+-------------------+
| Timestamp           | COUNT(visitor_id) |
+---------------------+-------------------+
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 45                |
| 2020-01-01 00:05:00 | 49                |
| 2020-01-01 00:10:00 | 37                |
...
```

This is something i'm currently calculating post-query but looking to shift some of the work to the MySQL server by doing it as part of the database query.

Comment: Are you really storing dates as integers? If so, what do they look like, are they unix timestamps?

Comment: How do you capture the `start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` of a visitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use a recursive query to generates the intervals, then bring your table with a `left join`, and finally aggregate.

The following query gives you the information that you want for the current day (you can change `current_date` to some other date as needed):

```
with all_ts as (
    select current_date ts
    union all
    select ts + interval 5 minute 
    from all_ts 
    where ts < current_date + interval 1 day
)
select a.ts, count(t.visitor_id) no_visitors
from all_ts a
left join mytable t
    on  t.start_timestamp >= a.ts
    and t.end_timestamp   <  a.ts 
group by a.ts
```

If you are storing your dates as unix timestamps, you can change the `left join` as follows:

```
left join mytable t
    on  t.start_timestamp >= unix_timestamp(a.ts)
    and t.end_timestamp   <  unix_timestamp(a.ts)
```

Comment: Not using MySQL 8.0 but was able to select from another table to get the intervals then use your `left_join` example to bring in the visitor duration table and count the visitors. Thanks!